# Real-Time Audio Encoding With Azure Media Services

Tags: azure, audio, html5-audio, audio-streaming, azure-media-services

Is it possible to get real-time audio encoding using Azure Media Services? We have an ASP.NET MVC C# site that we want to allow our users to upload an audio file and then immediately play that audio file back using a standard HTML5 audio tag.

I know I can upload the audio asset to azure and then ask it to encode it into an MP3 file so that it can be played using the audio tag but there may be to much of a delay in that process. Is there a way to upload the asset and then ask azure for an MP3 stream that it would encode in real-time so that I can play it to the user immediately after the upload completes.

If it cannot be done with azure is there a different service that offers that capability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, we do not provide a real-time transcoding option where the playback request triggers a real-time transcode.

An option for you may be to run ffmpeg directly in an Azure Function.